# missing destructor declaration

Tags: c++, memory, destructor

Can anyone tell me what happens with object's memory if I forget to declare a destrucor in a C++ class? I mean, whether it is freed or causes memory leak?
An example or demo will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends on your class. show an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's often considered good practice to define a destructor for any non-trivial class (see the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)). However, in modern C++ (i.e. C++11 onwards), it's not as necessary as it used to be.

If your class is not inherited from anything else, any direct members (such as variables and objects) will be properly destroyed by the default destructor provided by the compiler. Similarly, if your object owns any heap-allocated objects which are **wrapped in smart pointers**, they will be destroyed safely too.

A problem arises if your object owns any heap-allocated data via raw pointers. The implicit destructor has no way of knowing what to do with them, so you will need a custom destructor to clear them up. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    int m_data1;
    std::string m_data2;
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> m_data3;
    Widget *m_data4;
};
```

In the above example, members `m_data1`, `m_data2`, and `m_data3` will all be cleared-up correctly without a custom destructor. However, the object pointed to by `m_data4` will **not** be cleared up automatically. If it was allocated by `MyClass`, then it will usually result in a memory leak (unless it's getting freed by something else).

With all of that said, inheritance changes things in an important way. If your class is inherited by anything else then you should probably always give it a **virtual destructor**. If your object is deleted via a pointer to an inherited class, and that class does *not* have a virtual destructor, then the sub-class' destructor will never be called, potentially resulting in memory leaks.

For example:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Widget m_data1;
}

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Widget m_data2;
}

int main()
{
    Parent *ptr = new Child;
    delete ptr; // <-- clears-up Parent but not Child
}
```

In the above example, `ptr` is of `Parent` type, so the `delete` only knows about the `Parent` part of the object. That means only `m_data1` will be cleared-up correctly. Without a virtual destructor, it doesn't know about the `Child` part of the object, so `m_data2` will not be cleared-up correctly (its destructor will never be called).

Answer (score 2):

If destructor is not declared, compiler will generate destructor, that will call destructors of all members of object. Leak can be only if you are working with raw-memory (C files, memory allocation etc).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the class' data members. If the class manages resources, then it needs a destructor to release them (you should also provide a copy constructor and assignment operator, or make the class non-copyable and non-assignable).

If the class has built-in data members, or data members that manage their own resources, then the implicitly generated destructor is enough. It will call the destructor of all data members.